# Unity3D: How to call a method that instantiates a prefab from another class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object named *Player* and there are two scripts attached to it. The Player script is listening for input and calls a method from the second script named *LaserController*.

The second script is responsible for instantiating a prefab that has a LineRenderer component, and it controls how the line drawn and it's life-cycle. This prefab is attached to this script on the hierarchy.

If I merge these scripts into one class, there are no issues. But the way I'm using them is causing this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

*Player Class*

```
 public class Player : MonoBehaviour
 {
     LaserController laserController;

     void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
         {
             laserController.ShootLaserBeam(Input.mousePosition); // NullReferenceException is thrown 
         }
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
         {
             laserController.RemoveLaserBeam();
         }
     }
 }
```

Laser Controller Classs

```
 public class LaserController : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject laserPrefab;
     public GameObject laserInstance;

     public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
     public EdgeCollider2D edgeCollider;

     protected bool isBeamActive;

     public void ShootLaserBeam(Vector3 mousePosition)
     {
         if (isBeamActive == false)
         {
             CreateLaser(mousePosition);
         }
     }

     public void RemoveLaserBeam()
     {
         Destroy(edgeCollider);
         Destroy(laserInstance);
         isBeamActive = false;
     }

     private void CreateLaser(Vector3 mousePosition)
     {
         float turretY = transform.position.y;
         Vector2 turret = new Vector2(0, turretY);
         laserInstance = Instantiate(laserPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
         lineRenderer = laserInstance.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
         edgeCollider = laserInstance.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();

         isBeamActive = true;
         // do bunch of other things with the lineRenderer and Collider....
     }
 }
```

If the Controller script was attached to another object, I'd get why there's a reference error however both scripts are attached to the same object. I'd appreciate if someone can point out what I'm missing here.

Comment: Where does the nullreference Exception occur?

Comment: Added inline comment to where the exception occurs.

Comment: laserController is never assigned. You must assign some value to it before using it. You must assign it through inspector or use GetComponent<LaserController>().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a guess but laserController semms to be null. Since both scripts are on the same gameobject, you can define it with GetComponent.

Try changing

```
LaserController laserController;
```

To

```
LaserController laserController= this.GetComponent<LaserController>();
```

If you would have two gameobjects, one for Player and one for LaserController you could also decare the lasercontroller variable as public and define it by dragging the gameobject onto the variable in Unity.

Comment: I was specifically trying to handle it within the same game object, and this solution works for my case. I wonder if getting the second script using `GetComponent` would be more expensive compared to having two game objects connected via the hierarchy.

Comment: It depends very much on the code you are executing but for this specific example I assume one gameobject will be better for you.